# Can't show upload filed on php

Tags: php, ajax

Update : ok thank you for the help, I managed to make it work with a simple form to show the picture (video will come later) but i'm still stuck with ajax ... Just below is my coding attempt with ajax (for some reason it doesn't read the echo) and at the far end is my simpler coding form.

test.php code :

```
<input name="file" id="file" type="file" />
<br /><br />


<script>

var fileInput = document.querySelector('#file')
fileInput.onchange = function() {

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.open('POST', 'test2.php');

xhr.upload.onprogress = function(e) {
    progress.value = e.loaded;
    progress.max = e.total;
};

xhr.onload = function() {
    var uploadStatus = document.getElementById("finish");
    document.getElementById('finish').innerHTML = 'Upload done !';      
};

var form = new FormData();
form.append('file', fileInput.files[0]);

xhr.send(form);

};

</script>

<p id="finish">
</p>
```

test2.php code :

```
$filename = $_FILES['file']['name'];
$targetpath = getcwd() . '/' . $filename;
@move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $targetpath);
echo '<img src="' . $filename . '" height="100px" width="100px"/>';

?>
```

and the simple form code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<form method="post" action="test.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input name="file" id="file" type="file" accept="video/*" />
<br /><br />
<input type="submit"/>
</form>
<br/>

<?php 


$filename = $_FILES['file']['name'];
$targetpath = getcwd() . '/' . $filename;
@move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $targetpath);
echo '<img src="' . $filename . '" height="100px" width="100px"/>';

?>
```

ps: I clear the tags, sorry I was having problems with indents, and it still doesn't work .

Comment: have you tried looking at the generated source for the `img` tag at run time? The path might be invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Where to begin?

- <strike>You don't have a `</script>` tag.</strike>
- <strike>You have 3 `</body>` tags. Remove the first 2 and only leave the last one.</strike>
- <strike>And 2 `</html>` tags. Remove the first 1 and only leave the last one.</strike>
- The web server stores the file at `$_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]`, not at `$_FILES['file']['name']`. (The last one is just the original file name, as it was uploaded in the browser.
- You need to move the temporary file to a locations of your choosing that has to be writable for the web server, as the temporary file will be deleted after the upload request is done.
- You have the $name already inside $path, but you echo $path with $name again. While you shouldn't echo any of them. You should echo the the path and filename where you moved the temporary file to.